# Unity: How do I upgrade my materials to be HDRP compatible?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have recently tried to upgrade my unity pipeline to the HDRP to do this I went into package manager and enabled preview packages then installed HDRP when it had finished the HDRP render pipeline wizard appeared and I clicked fix all my scene now looks like this

[image: image of what the scene looks like]

the skybox has changed the entire scene seems to be shaded black and some of my materials have turned purple I understand to an extent why the last one has happened because they need to be HDRP shaders but I don't know how to fix it. This is my first unity game and I'm very new so if anyone can help pleas make it as simple as possible. I did make a backup before switching to HDRP.

Comment: I had the same problem and manually changed the shader for each material and fixed the textures assigned. Not sure if there's an automatic way.

Comment: it looks like you can navigate to Edit > Render Pipeline> Upgrade Project Materials to High Definition Materials

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade all project materials to **HDRP** automatically, you have to go to **Edit / Render Pipeline /** and click on **/Upgrade Project Materials to High Definition Materials**

All your project materials will be changed to HDRP materials, avoiding errors.